# Where to see the last Arabian flag in Andalus (Spain) and history of Andalus in general

Tags: spain, museums

In which museum in Spain I can find the last flag of the Arabian armies that used to occupy Spain for 700 years ([Andalus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Andalus)). All I find about it in the net is this photo which seems like a festival for Spanish victory in the last war with Arabs:

[image: Islamic flag in Andalus]

**In which museum  I can see this flag? Or any museum  about the Andalus in general?**

Comment: So this is where the name Andalusia comes from!  I learned something today :)

Comment: @MarkMayo I am 300% sure. The name of this festival is **curpillos** and it is about the last battle between Arabs and natives in that area "**Battle of Las Navas de Tolosa**" in which Arabs had that flag. The problem here all resources are either in Arabic or Spanish...

Comment: BTW, This is the flag of the Arab Army "Mohads army". not the Flag of Andalus itself.

Comment: They have a flag on that page on the right which is quite different to the one you present in the photo above?

Comment: I do not know about that Flag, But I am 100% sure the flag in the photo is the Army Flag.

Comment: The Arabs didn't occupy spain for 700 years lol that's only Andalusia, or specifically Granada. That's like saying for example if mexico becomes part of the US today it means that the US has been occupied by Mexicans for more than 500 years lol which is totally stupid. The Arabs were being pushed slowly out of the Uberian Peninsula, at that time there was no spain, bu many different kingdoms that later united to become spain. So saying that Spain has been ruled by Arabs for 700 years is wrong!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Abbey of Santa María la Real de Las Huelgas (Burgos)
(El monasterio de Santa María la Real de Las Huelgas – Burgos)
is a monastery of Cistercian nuns located approximately 1.5 km west of the city of Burgos in Spain.
The monastery is open to the public. Visits are administered not by the monastic community, but by the Spanish heritage organisation Patrimonio Nacional, which maintains the property as a Spanish royal site. on display is : 
The tapestry that covered the tent (not the last Arabian flag) of the Almohad caliph Al Nasir, known to the Christians as Miramamolin. This tapestry was seized by the victorious Christians at the Battle of Las Navas de Tolosa on July 16, 1212. When Sancho VII of Navarre's men drove through an enchained circle of African slaves guarding Miramamolin's tent, the caliph fled with great haste, leaving this tapestry along with several other prizes of war behind for the exultant Spanish.

Comment: I always thought it is the Flag.. Thanks for the great info.

Comment: Hah, @Larbi, I came to add what you'd emailed me, and I see you've signed up anyway :) Fantastic.

Comment: @HaLaBi: note that if this is the flag, it was most definitely not the last flag or last war of the Arabs in Andalusia. The Nasrid dynasty in Granada lasted until 1492.

Answer (score 6):

Right, after some investigation, there are a few museums in Spain related to Al-Andalus and that time period.  Which one has the flag in, though, I'm not sure.

However, here are some useful links that may aid in your search:

- [Al-Andalus living museum – Calahorra Tower](http://www.spain.info/en/conoce/museo/cordoba/museo_vivo_de_al_andalus_torre_de_la_calahorra.html) (Torre de Calahorra) - looks to be about your best bet.  The museum is located in an old Moorish fortress, and recreates the time of maximum splendour in this Andalusian city.  Its aim is to provide a recreation of the Cordoba of the period between the 9th-13th centuries, at a time of brilliant cultural, artistic and scientific achievement.
- [Another page about the Calahorra Tower](http://www.artencordoba.co.uk/MUSEUMS/Museums-Cordoba-Calahorra-Tower-Living-Museum-Al-Andalus.html), with a gallery. No sign of the flag though.
- [Al-Andalus Expert](http://al-andalus-expert.com/) - this guy is a tour guide of the area, speaks Arabic, English and Spanish, and is probably the best bet for someone to answer where the flag might be.
- [A page on the above expert's website on a list of museums in the Andalus(ia) area](http://al-andalus-expert.com/al-andalus-museums.html)